# Azure SQL PaaS - Limitations

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-active-directory

We are trying to evaluate possibility of migrating our in-house SQL DB server to Azure SQL as a PaaS.

Our legacy windows application which is written in VB6 and now running on VB.NET Framework 4.5

Clarifications I need if I migrate only DB server to Azure:

1. We use both trusted / credential based SQL connection from our desktop application to connect to SQL DB. If we migrate to Azure SQL, will it support trusted connection which should authenticate current organizations NT user?
2. We have lot of cross DB queries, do we need to face any challenge to use the queries as it is?
3. Run time we take a DB backup / restore for some business cases. Does this work?
4. Are there any restrictions on number of admin users on Azure DB?

Answer (score 0):

1. Probably yes if you sync your local AD with an AAD (See: [Use Azure Active Directory Authentication for authentication with SQL Database, Managed Instance, or SQL Data Warehouse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication))
2. Azure SQL Database (PaaS) doesn't support cross DB queries by default - you have to setup / use Elastic Query for that.
3. Yes, you can take a DB backup at runtime and also restore it. There is also a point-in-time restore feature available. See: [Learn about automatic SQL Database backups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-automated-backups).
4. I think you can only specify one server administrator (at least within the portal) but I doubt you will reach any limit on db users.

Instead of using the single database SQL Server PaaS service you should also consider using [Managed Instance (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance)

Comment: pretty sure you cant create backups, only bacpacs.

Answer (score 0):

1. You will have to extend your active directory to Azure active directory to keep using trusted connections. You will learn how to do it on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure) documentation and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication) one.
2. On Azure SQL Database you have elastic queries that allow you to run cross database queries. Learn how to create elastic queries [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/querying-remote-databases-in-azure-sql-db/).
3. You can create bacpacs (export your databases) to Azure Storage or to on-premises location very easy.
4. You can configure one Server Admin or one Azure Active Directory Admin (it can be a group) for your Azure SQL Server. However, at the database level you can add many database users to the dbmanager role. You can have more information about this topic [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-manage-logins).

Comment: Great! Does all these features available with AWS aswell? if not as PaaS at least as IaaS. Any reference would be appreciated.

Comment: I have never used AWS. Sorry.